# Github action test if a commit containing a specific word was previously made

Tags: github, build, yaml, action, github-actions

I need to make sure to test with github action, if a commit has previously been made that contains the word `build`.
If the commit does not contain the word `build` then tests with github action should not be run.

Can you give me some advice?

Test:

```yaml
name: "Testing"

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  test_the_action:
    name: Test the action
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2          
      - uses: suisei-cn/actions-download-file@master
        id: downloadfile
        name: Download a file
        with:
          url: "[API Endpoint](https://api.github.com/repos/suisei-cn/actions-download-file)"
          target: public/
          auto-match: true

      - name: Display the file
        run: head -n8 public/actions-download-file
```

Comment: why dont you do the conditional trigger to the `test` flow from the `build` flow?

Comment: @chenrui: What do you mean?

Answer (score 14):

From a push event, it's possible to extract the commit message by using `github.event.commit.message`

Here is an example of the [github context for a push event](https://gist.github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/81f41fb8b53a0bd3d63856f919e501c2).

Note that if there are several commit messages:

- `commit[0]` contains the **oldest** commit

```
${{ github.event.commits[0].message }}
```

- `head_commit` contains the **youngest** commit

```
${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}
```

Then, you can check in your job if the commit message contains or not the word you want, for example by using:

```yaml
if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'build')"
```

Therefore, your workflow could look like this if you don't want the job to be run if the commit message contains the 'build' word:

```yaml
name: "Testing"

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  test_the_action:
    if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'build')"
    name: Test the action
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2          
      - uses: suisei-cn/actions-download-file@master
        id: downloadfile
        name: Download a file
        with:
          url: "[API Endpoint](https://api.github.com/repos/suisei-cn/actions-download-file)"
          target: public/
          auto-match: true

      - name: Display the file
        run: head -n8 public/actions-download-file
```

Finally, you now also have the option to [skip ci workflows with key words in the commit messages](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-02-08-github-actions-skip-pull-request-and-push-workflows-with-skip-ci/).

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTI6W.png

Comment: It may be due to the `!` character in the if expression, could you add `"` quotes around the expression? `if: "!contains(...)"` (I updated the answer)

Comment: sure it should be github.event.commit.message and not github.event.head_commit.message?

Comment: Take a look at the code: https://www.shorturl.at/xMV67
You find it in the `testing` branch.

Comment: What needs to happen is this:
When the file is modified for example `index.js`.
Action `Test` must not run.
Action `Build` has to run, which builds and then loads the updated build file.
With a Bot commit called `[Build]`.

The test must be started after the bot is committed, called `[Build]`.

But it doesn't happen.

Comment: It also seems that when a bot is committed, actions such as `console` do not fire.
Instead it should always fire on every commit.

Comment: To achieve what you want, I would actually use a `repository dispatch` event with a `event-type` instead of the commit name. However, to do it you would need to use a PAT as repo secret, and commit everything to the `default` branch (repository dispatch event doesn't work if not present on default branch).

Comment: I tested it here: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/actions-download-file and it's working. Workflow `build.yml` would only trigger workflow `testing.yml` on a commit without the specific word, throw a repository dispatch event. You can see the runs here: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/actions-download-file/actions where the `build` workflow has been triggered from the master, and the `testing` workflow only afterwards through this dispatch event (no branch reference)

Comment: I'm testing your example, but I'm getting the following error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QItXd.png

Comment: Then I don't understand the build is done, but no change commits to the distribution.

Comment: The error is because you need to add a PAT (Personnal Access Token) to the repository secrets and use it in the repository dispatch action (in the build workflow).

Comment: Using a dispatch event, you wouldn't need an additional commit, as the own repository dispatch action would trigger the other workflow for you everytime the condition is met (commit without `[Build]` message in the build workflow)

Comment: Ok, I succeeded I created the `PAT` or put the `PAT` in the `ACCESS_TOKEN`.

Comment: I modified the `index.js` file the` Build action` is started but no commit is created that modifies the `distribution` file for me.
It is not even called the `action test`.
I'm testing everything on the `testing` branch.

Comment: Maybe now I have managed to get it to build with commit, but the test action is not called.

Comment: I used the workflows you shared from the repository. If you need to update a file before triggering the other workflow for downloading the file, you would indeed need to push the updated file in the workflow. In that case, it would be worth triggering the other workflow using a path-filter action or something similar. Regarding the tests on the testing branch, dispatches only work using the default branch workflows (generally main ou master branches).