# Github actions, how to pass variable to set-output

Tags: bash, github, github-actions

I'm using `set-output` to define an output for my steps. I want the output to be the value of the commit message (which in my case will always be a short string).

I tried to set it like this:

```
      - name: Store commit message for folder name
        run: echo ::set-output name=TEXT::$(echo ${{github.event.head_commit.message}})
        id: folder-name
```

And use it like this:

```
      - name: Create directory
        run: 'mkdir -p ${{steps.folder-name.outputs.TEXT}}'
```

But this returns an error: `mkdir: missing operand. Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`

Comment: Could you share the whole workflow in the question? Are those steps in the same job? Did you try printing the output value directly before using it to check if it was empty or not? Another question: Why not using directly `mkdir -p ${{github.event.head_commit.message}}`?

Comment: I just tried to print the value directly and it is empty. Looks like the commit message is not actually being sent, set or received somehow. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You may have some insights in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71361539/github-action-test-if-a-commit-containing-a-specific-word-was-previously-made/71364384#71364384) as well.  You could also print the GITHUB_CONTEXT to check what is available ([as commented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68061051/get-commit-sha-in-github-actions/68068674#68068674))

Comment: I was using the wrong variable in the end. I should have used `${{ github.event.client_payload.commitMessage }}`